# Should not NumberStyles.AllowThousands only allow separator in thousand place in en-US culture?

Tags: c#, .net-4.5, number-formatting

I want to only allow numeric string value with comma in thousand places but 
this code is not working and successfully parses the "2,22" which does not have comma in thousand places.

```
   double dollarValue;
           var dollarStringValue="2,22";
            var usCulture = CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("en-US");
            var allowedNumberStyle = NumberStyles.AllowThousands | NumberStyles.AllowDecimalPoint;
            if (double.TryParse(dollarStringValue, allowedNumberStyle, usCulture, out dollarValue))
            { 
            // This is parsed successfully to 222
             Console.WriteLine(dollarValue);
            }
```

Is this the intended behavior of NumberStyles.AllowThousands in en-Us culture(It has NumberFormatInfo.NumberGroupSizes set to 3)? or am I missing sth?

Using .Net 4.5

Comment: It will only ignore any thousands separators while parsing the string

Comment: It is very forgiving about where the user types the comma.  AllowThousands merely signals that commas are acceptable, it doesn't not enforce where they appear.  Not the kind of problem that is really a problem.

Comment: Such a misnomer :)

Comment: For TryParse with AllowThousands to accept 2,22 seems entirely unacceptable to me.  If the user enters wants to enter a million, but accidentally enters [1,000,0000] it will be accepted as ten million.  I'd say that's a bug in TryParse.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to verify that a string Matches a pattern n,nnn,nnn,nnn... try a regular expression, something like

```
Regex r = new Regex(@"^\d{1,3}(,\d\d\d)*$");
if(r.IsMatch(yourNumber))
  ...
```

Answer (score 0):

My answer here would be:

**Yes, it should only allow thousands separators to appear in the thousands place, but it does not behave correctly.**

I would argue that the behavior you describe in your question is a bug, and that "AllowThousands" is indeed a misnomer.  It should perhaps be called "IgnoreThousandsSeparators".

If a user is intending to enter **one million**, and enters it as [1,000,0000] (accedentally entering an extra zero) TryParse will accept this as **ten million**.  To me, that's a potentially pretty bad bug.